# Are functions $f(x)=\sin^2x-\sin^4x$, $g(x)=\cos^2x-\cos^4x$ equal or not? Why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

We have two functions named $f$ and $g$.
$$f(x)=\sin^2x-\sin^4x$$
$$g(x)=\cos^2x-\cos^4x$$
find out that they are equal functions or not.
My problem is with:

1. finding their domain
2. if we choose any $x$ from $D_f=D_g$ , then we have $$f(x)=g(x)$$

Please help me with the whole entry! 
I dont know how to calculate their doamins and having trouble in step 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, by simple algebra,

$\sin^4 x - \cos^4 x = (\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x)(\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x) = (\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x)(1) = \sin^2 x - \cos^2 x, \tag 1$

and thus, again by simple algebra

$f(x) = \sin^2 x - \sin^4 x = \cos^2 x - \cos^4 x = g(x), \tag 2$

wherever both $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are defined; since the domain of each is $\Bbb R$, we have

$D_f = \Bbb R = D_g \tag 3$

as well, and we have seen above that

$\forall x \in \Bbb R, \; f(x) = g(x). \tag 4$

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert  for your explanations. Robert it might be a personal question but i am eager to know that are you in euroup?

Comment: I want to chat with someone and gain information about euroup.

Comment: @user602338:   No, sorry.  I'm in Santa Barbara, California, on the west coast of the USA.

Comment: If you are in america not important i want gain some information about there too

Comment: @user602338:  OK.  Try me in chat!

Comment: I know Mr.Lewis you are now 68 and  a very experienced person! You are rare here i think!

Comment: Do you have enough time?

Comment: It might take us about a quarter!

Comment: But experience is better than time! My qoute! Hh

Comment: I have a little time.  Message me.  Also, if you liked my answer you might consider upvoting/accepting it.  Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86805/discussion-between-user602338-and-robert-lewis).

Comment: Thanks again! 

Comment: Please join me in discussion room

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
Use the identity
$$
\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1
$$
to show that $$f(x)=\sin^2 x\cos^2 x=g(x).$$ Both $f$ and $g$ have as their domain $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Really sorry but i didn't understand. Why f(x)=sin^2xcos^2x ???